# What's the difference between 'with command' and 'fluent interface' in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, with-statement, fluent-interface

Why should I use fluent interface in Delphi instead of using 'with command'?

I heard about both, but I haven't found the difference. I'm trying to find the best one for my project. ​It seems to work in the same way, just with some grammar differences.

Comment: This is like asking, "When should I use umbrellas and when should I use the present participle"?

Comment: I want to dispute the premise that you should use one or the other.

Comment: The `with .. ` has been in Delphi at least since the 1990s. I use it in D6.

Comment: I personally don't use either. I think that `sBuilder1.Append('one');
sBuilder1.Append('two');` is easier to understand and maintain than `with sBuilder1 do begin Append('one'); Append('two'); end;` and also easier to understand and maintain than `sBuilder1.Append('one').Append('two');`

Comment: If you use a fluent interface, the scope of what you're working on is clear. When you use the with command you can often not see what the scope of your code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some (very, very few) use cases where `with` is "safe" to use but should otherwise be avoided.

So I am specifically not going to get into (in detail) why you should or should not use `with` and stick to answering the second part of your question: the apparent misunderstanding that `with` and fluent APIs are somehow directly related when they really are not.

### `with`

`with` takes one or more symbols and creates a scope in which those symbols takes precedence over other symbols with the same name in the containing scope:

So if we imagine we are writing code on some form and need to set multiple  properties of some component on that form where some of those properties are also present (i.e. with the same name) on the form class itself, we can use `with` to create a scope in which an unqualified reference to those properties resolves to the component, not the form:

```pascal
procedure frmMain.ButtonClick(Sender TComponent);
begin 
   with foo do
   begin
      Caption := 'click me!';
      Tag     := 42;
   end;
end;
```

The alternative is to not use `with` and instead use qualified references to the properties of `foo`:

```pascal
procedure frmMain.ButtonClick(Sender TComponent);
begin 
   foo.Caption := 'click me!';
   foo.Tag     := 42;
end;
```

This is clearly not a "fluent" API.  So what is?

### Fluent API

A fluent API is a term used to describe a pattern where methods of an object return a reference to that object, allowing further methods to be called by chaining them.

Sticking with the hypothetical `foo` component, if we imagine that the developer of that component had provided a fluent api for setting properties instead of (or perhaps as well as) directly exposing them as properties, then we could imagine it might be possible to write code similar to this:

```pascal
procedure frmMain.ButtonClick(Sender TComponent);
begin 
   foo.SetCaption('click me!')
      .SetTag(42);
end;
```

`SetCaption()` and `SetTag()` return the object on which they are called, allowing further calls to that object to be chained together.

This superficially looks similar, although less "wordy", to the `with` pattern, with two key differences:

1. the fluent api call is a single statement; the `with` approach involves *multiple* statements
2. the fluent api calls are made to an *explicitly* identified object; the calls made using `with` *implicitly* identify the target object

The confusion of `with` and fluent APIs perhaps stems from the fact that the use of `with` *in conjunction with* a fluent api *is* essentially just a variation in grammar:

```pascal
procedure frmMain.ButtonClick(Sender TComponent);
begin 
   with foo do
   begin
     SetCaption('click me!')
     SetTag(42);
   end
end;
```

But the key differences remain.  The above code is *two* statements *implicitly* using `foo` vs the *single* statement *explicitly* calling `foo` in the fluent variant.

A significant additional difference is that `with` can be used with *multiple symbols* (if you are absolutely determined to make your life and that of your colleagues difficult :)).  This has (hopefully) obvious potential to make it difficult to tell (at a glance) which references in a `with` scope resolve to which symbols.

A fluent api, on the other hand, always starts with some object, and the chain always continues with that object.  There is never any question or doubt about what symbol you are dealing with.

Just for fun, we can show that `with` and fluency are orthogonal by looking at how the two could be used *together* to create a real monstrosity:

```pascal
procedure frmMain.ButtonClick(Sender TComponent);
begin 
   with foo do
   begin
     SetCaption('click me!')
     .SetTag(42);
   end;
end;
```

### So what is the similarity?

The only real similarity is that a fluent api provides much the same benefit of not having to qualify every call (or, more accurately, *by making the qualification of each subsequent call part of the previous call*).

One of the big problems with `with` is that the debugger and IDE tooling to this day remains unable to resolve the symbols in the same way that the compiler does, which can lead to significant issues when trying to debug code in a `with` statement.  Inspecting a `with` scoped value in the debugger can resolve to the wrong symbol, giving the wrong value.

Fluent APIs have their own debugging challenges, the most obvious being that a chained sequence of fluent api calls is a single statement on which only a single breakpoint may be placed.

### Which should you use?

#### As the consumer of an api...

If you are faced with a scenario where you don't have a fluent api to work with, there is no choice between `with` and a fluent api.  Only a decision whether to use `with` or not.  Which is a long-running and heated debate.

The short answer to this is (IMHO): *don't use `with` unless/until you have confidently identified the (very, **very** few) edge cases where it is safe and beneficial to do so*.  In the meantime, default to "don't".

If there is a fluent api, then use it.  It provides very comparable syntactic shorthand without the pitfalls of `with`, though at the expense of some lack of granularity when it comes to breakpoints, as mentioned.

The third alternative, of course, is to use neither `with` nor fluency and simply take a reference to the "root" of the fluent api chain and use that in separate statements rather than chaining calls.

#### As the developer of an api

Think about how your code will be used and consider whether a fluent api makes sense.  "Builder" type APIs very commonly use fluent APIs, and there are other use cases, but some fluent APIs are very unintuitive and can be cumbersome to use; they are not a panacea.

And if you run into an edge case in your api where fluency isn't possible, you risk leaving your consumers in the uncomfortable position of using fluency in some areas but not being able to in others, which can be very frustrating having to remember which parts of your api work in which ways.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Upvoted, even though I don't agree with you on `with` being that bad, because that was a very comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above explanation is great, but it's unclear from your question what you're looking for. Here's a slightly different take.

Suppose you have a class TFoo with a few different methods. In your code, you might have an occasion to write something like this:

```
foo.turnOn;
foo.doThis;
foo.Caption := 'a caption';
foo.Update( aRecPtr );
foo.turnOff;
```

The use of 'with' can be done very easily:

```
with foo do
begin
  turnOn;
  doThis;
  Caption := 'a caption';
  Update( aRecPtr );
  turnOff;
end;
```

Using a 'fluent' approach won't work directly in this case because none of these methods are likely to return a reference to foo. (You might notice that none of the VCL methods are designed for this.) So you'll need to rewrite the ones you need (or the entire class) so you can do the following:

```
foo.turnOn
   .doThis
   .Caption( 'a caption' )
   .Update( aRecPtr )
   .turnOff;
```

This isn't very hard, and you can create a Helper class for whatever type 'foo' is. Each one needs to be a function that returns the base type:

```
type
TFooHelper = class helper for TFoo
  function turnOn : TFoo;
  function Caption( const str : string ) : TFoo;
end;

function TFooHelper.turnOn : TFoo;
begin
  self.turnOn;  // Self refers to TFoo type, not TFooHelper
  Result := self;
end;

function TFooHelper.Caption( const str : string ) : TFoo;
begin
  self.Caption := str;
  Result := self;
end;
```

and so forth.